# Lex Flex variant that will do the Perl REGEX extensions

Tags: perl, regex

I use flex & lex a lot for stripping stuff from e-mail attachments in scritps. I wondered if there are moden versions and variants of the lex programs that have the perl REGEX extensions.

I know the boost libs support perl style but this is not quite what I am looking for.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [Pro Perl Parsing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590595041) to be a good book on the topic, covers grammars and lexing themselves as well as different cpan modules.

Answer (score 3):

Follow this article about [lexing with perl](http://www.perl.com/lpt/a/969).